# How I can route to another route if router.navigate returns false Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

In my case, user can try to login and route to last opened page, but if it user tries to login by another account and this account don't has permissions to this page it will be 'no permissions' page with error.     But second route doesn't routes to another path
I tried to catch this by code:

```
this.router.navigate([hash]).then((result) => {
          if(!result) {
            hash = dashboardPath;
            this.router.navigate([hash])
          }
        })
```

Comment: Have you tried to add authorization? https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inferring from your question that you are using a CanActivate route, and I suppose you are returning "false" in case the route is not authorized.

You have a couple of options:

- trigger a `navigate` to the dashboard in the same way you are doing now. If it doesn't work, it means the router has not yet completed the current navigation. You just need to wrap the call to `router.navigate` into a `settimeout(() => this.router.navigate(...), 0)`, in order to allow the router to complete the current operation.
- my preferred solution: have the guard return an Observable instead of an Observable (both are suported by the CanActivate signature). Returning `of(this.router.parseUrl(dashboardPath))` inside the guard is simple and direct.